# C bind to a specified TCP port

Tags: c, networking, port, bind

i have created a Linux network app with C and it kind of works

except that it every time i run it , it binds to a new Random port

```
//Create Socket
int socket_desc;
socket_desc=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if (socket_desc==-1)
  perror("Create socket");
struct sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
//Port defined Here:
address.sin_port=htons(81);
//Bind
bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&address,sizeof(address));
listen(socket_desc,32);
//Do other stuff (includes accepting connections)
```

as you can see i have specified port but it still chooses a free Random port

any help or link to a good tutorial on this is appreciated

Comment: non-root user can't bind port under 1024, your bind may fail, and you didn't check that. Try `strace` it

Comment: what is the output of "netstate -l --tcp" while your code is running ?
Can you see your process listening or your port ?

Comment: Did you tried giving a port no greater then 1024? Try it. it'll work

Comment: netstat says my app is listening , but on a +50000 random port , i will check +1024 port now

Comment: Always _always_ **always** check the return values of functions that can fail. All of the system calls you use will return `-1` on failure. You can then check [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno) what the error was, and use e.g. [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) to get a printable string of the error, or use [`perror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror) to print it out directly.

Comment: @Aadietya post that as answer , that was the problem :| it works on port 1050

Comment: @joachim can you post an example code of how to correctly check if bind was successful or not? i'm not very good at C coding ...

Comment: `if (bind(...) == -1) ERROR`

Comment: You already do it for the `socket` call. Just keep doing it for the other functions. Also I recommend you look at the functions manual pages. A set of online manual pages can be found [here](http://linux.die.net/man/).

Comment: @Bor691 posted it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use port number greater than 1024. Port numbers less then 1024 are reserved ports and are used by standard services.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons of this behaviour (when you specify port, but system binds socket to a random one):

> 1. If you ask for port below 1024. This is certainly your case
> 2. If you forgot to use `htons()` function. In this case bytes of port number are used in wrong order and that leads to #1.